# AWS CentOS 6.5 Instance + AWS EBS volume for web hosting files and database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, mount

I have an AWS instance running CentOS 6.5. It has been updated, secured, and setup for web hosting (LAMP). I attached an EBS volume to the instance and mounted it under `/data`.

Two questions:

1. How can I get MySQL to use the `/data` directory as its database storage location? (I don't want to run the program from the `/data` directory, just put the .sql file there.
2. How can I do the same for my web site? I plan on running a wordpress site and its current location is in the `/var/www/html` directory. I want to change this to    `/data/site`.

I want to keep the web site files and database on a separate volume: `/data`. If my instance was to get corrupt or inaccessible, I can attach the EBS volume to a new instance.

I have read dozens of tutorials and articles on how to get MySQL moved to a different directory, but nothing is working. MySQL refuses to start up after. Can I keep MySQL installed as is, but have it read/write the database on a different directory like `/data` which is a mounted EBS volume or is this not possible at all with linux?

Here are some of the tutorials and articles I been following/testing with:

`aws.amazon.com/articles/1663?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1`

`spruce.it/noise/setting-up-a-proper-lamp-stack-on-aws-ec2-ebs/`

EDIT:
This is what I am doing.

1. Create a new instance using this ami: `https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00IOYDTV6?ref=cns_srchrow`
2. Once the instance is up, I run updates using: `sudo yum update -y`
3. One updated, I set it up as a LAMP web server using these instructions: `http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html`
   In addition to the above steps, I allow port 80 tcp connections on the built-in firewall. I run these commands: `sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` and `sudo service iptables save`
   Once this is done, I test my site at `http://IP-ADDRESS` (this shows me the Apache Test Page)
4. Once LAMP is installed, I install the MySQL Server by running this: `yum install mysql-server`
   After that is installed, I proceed to the "To secure the MySQL server" instructions on the previous Amazon document.
5. Next, I install PHPMyAdmin using these two tutorials: `http://tecadmin.net/installing-apache-mysql-php-on-centos-redhat/#` and `http://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-centos-using-yum/`
6. At this point, I have a fully functioning web server. Now, I want to use the AWS EBS volume to store all the databases and website files. First, I attach the newly create AWS EBS volume. I use this tutorial to do this: `http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html`

THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEMS START.
Using the information in this tutorial: `aws.amazon.com/articles/1663?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1`. It says FAILED.

Comment: What error messages are you seeing ?  Can you elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: I added some more information about my procedure above.

Answer (score 0):

So one thing you can do is the following that avoids copying all directories.  You need to make sure that all permissions are setup correctly for it to work:

- mysql dat dir:

  ```
  mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.orig
  mkdir -p /<your-new-ebs-mountpoint>/var/lib/mysql
  chown mysql.mysql /<your-new-ebs-mountpoint>/var/lib/mysql
  chmod 700 /<your-new-ebs-mountpoint>/var/lib/mysql
  ```
- etc configs:

  ```
  mkdir -p /<your-new-ebs-mountpoint>/etc
  cp /etc/my.cnf /<your-new-ebs-mountpoint>/etc/my.cnf
  mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.orig
  ln -s /<your-new-ebs-mountpoint>/etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf
  ```
- logs:

  ```
  mkdir -p /<your-new-ebs-mountpoint>/var/log
  mv /var/log/mysqld.log /var/log/mysqld.log.orig
  touch /<your-new-ebs-mountpoint>/var/log/mysqld.log
  chown mysql.mysql /<your-new-ebs-mountpoint>/var/log/mysqld.log
  chmod 640 /<your-new-ebs-mountpoint>/var/log/mysqld.log
  ln -s /<your-new-ebs-mountpoint>/var/log/mysqld.log /var/log/mysqld.log
  ```